# Veronese surface in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am working on the following excercise:
 Let $F:R^3\to R^6$ be given by $F(x,y,z)=(x^2,y^2,z^2,\sqrt{2}xy,\sqrt{2}xz,\sqrt{2}yz)$.

i) Show that $M=F(R^3-\{0\})$ is a submanifold of $R^6$.

ii) Show that the intersection of $M$ with $S^5$ is a submanifold of $S^5$ diffeomorphic to $RP^2$, called Veronese surface.

I have trouble finding which atlas I should equip the intersection with. I understand that it will be a 2-submanifold of $S^5$. My guess is that it would locally be the graph of function, but I coulnd't work that idea through the equation of the 5-sphere. Any ideas?

Comment: Two hints: Don't work with charts — either show $F$ is an immersion away from the origin or give equations for the image, then equations for the image intersected with the sphere.  What can you say about $\|F(x,y,z)\|^2$? If you restrict $F$ to the unit sphere, where does it map? What do you notice about $F(-x,-y,-z)$? Does that suggest something about $\Bbb RP^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin  thank you,I really appreciate your answer!! I'll work on those ideas and let you know if thats OK.

Comment: @TedShifrin F is an immersion, because the rank of its Jacobian equals the dimension of $R^3$.Therefore M is a 3 -submanifold of $R^6$. In addition, the only points of the image that lie on the shere $S^5$ are those $F(x,y,z)$ that the triple lies on the 2-sphere of $R^3$..Antipodical point of $S^2$ have the same image under F and now it is easy to deffine a diffemorphism from $S^2/~$, which is diffeomorphic to $P^2$, to M$\intersection$$S^5$...

Comment: Sounds like you've done it!!

Comment: @TedShifrin I think so too..Thanks again, your comments were of great help!!